# How to get data from MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, database, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have a database named as "test" in which I have a table named as "first" which contains  raw data, I want to get this table data. What should be the prepare statement I have to use in order to get data from table "first" ? Below is the code I am trying. Any help or guidance would be appreciable.

```
@Path("/database") // Specific URL
@GE
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String returnDB_Status() throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement query = null;
    String result = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = mysql_prac.dbConn().getConnection(); // this works fine ... 
        query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from first" ); // Table named as "first" is placed inside the connected database.
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
        result = "Data received : " + rs;
        query.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the source code used get a connection

```
public class mysql_prac {

    private static DataSource mysql_prac = null;
    private static Context context = null;

    public static DataSource dbConn() throws Exception {
        if (mysql_prac != null) {
            return mysql_prac;
        }

        try {
            if (context == null) {
                context = new InitialContext();
            }

            mysql_prac = (DataSource) context.lookup("JDBC_ref"); //JNDI ID (JDBC_REF)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return mysql_prac;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear. WHat are you trying to achieve. Please add additional information.

Comment: What's already the return of the code you posted? No results? Any exceptions?

Comment: @tmarwen ... It is giving me blank page (no output). If I print some thing after getting connection; it shows the print statement in eclipse but not getting any data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You must loop through the `ResultSet` to get the fields of each row. So I made the following edit together with some comments.Please notice the comments.

```
try {
        conn = mysql_prac.dbConn().getConnection(); // this works fine ... 
        query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from first" ); // Table named as "first" is placed inside the connected database.
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();//You must loop through the results set to get the fields of each row

        while(rs.next()){
            String dbUserID = rs.getString("column1");//this is just an example to retrieve all data in the column called 'column1'
            result = "Data received : " + dbUserID;
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        query.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }
```